# How to append an Html.Action to the jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

can i add

```
$("#report").html('Html.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId })')
```

here the report is the id of the div where i want to place the result of the action ReportPage id is the parameter passing to the ReportPage actionresult

Answer (score 5):

You need to use server tags in order to achieve this. So:

```
$("#report").html('@Html.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId })')
```

or

```
$("#report").html('<%= Html.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId }) %>')
```

if this is what you mean by ***result of the action ReportPage***.

But if by ***result of the action ReportPage*** you mean the actual result that your MVC action resturns (ie: a view, json ..) you must use something like this

```
$.get('@Html.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId })', function(data) {
  $("#report").html(data);
});
```

Hope this helps

PS: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ on more details regarding jQuery.get()

Answer (score 0):

This way, your action html will be loaded by ajax after the main page loading.

css

```
.support {display: hidden;}
```

html

```
<div class="support">
    <div class="report-page">
        <a href="Url.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId })" />
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var url = $('.support .report-page a').prop('href');
$.get(url, null, function(html){
    $('#report').html(html);
}, html);
```

---

Or, if you want only one http request, you can do this:

css

```
.support {display: hidden;}
```

html

```
<div class="support">
    <div class="report-page">
        @Html.Action("ReportPage", new { id = Model.GoalId })
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var html = $('.support .report-page').html();
$('#report').html(html);
```