# Unable to call @Html.Action() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get the html from one of my partial views into a div tag with the id "searchpage" in my main view. However, when I follow the syntax in this answer, [How to append an Html.Action to the jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289222/how-to-append-an-html-action-to-the-jquery), I get the error in chrome developer tools,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The code is

```
$("#searchbutton").click(function () {
    $("#searchpage").html('@Html.Action("Search", "Employees")');
});
```

The error is highlighted at `('` specifically.

Comment: Are you doing this within a view? You can't use the HtmlHelper within a .js file.

Comment: @Tieson T. I am doing this within the view, not an external .js file.

Comment: I have updated again it should work now with @Html.Raw(Html.Action("Search", "Employees"));

Comment: `@Html.Action()` is razor code. It is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Javascript is client side code and does not exist at that point. If you want to load html from the server based on a client side event, you need ajax to call a server method and add the partial view it returns in the success callback

Comment: StephenMuecke is right. I have tried @Html.Action with jquery in my mvc project the it returned with data but jquery/javascript could not interpret it. so i changed my answer according to this expeirence. I can advice jquery load function  or jquery ajax function in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Action:`  Returns only an url.

`@Html.Action:` Invokes the specified controller name and action and returns as a html string

You can not use `$("#yourid").html('@Html.Action()')` because this executes Html.Action and returns data but jquery can not see it as a variable and can not interpret it as we expected.

There are good two options to achieve your goal:

First one is using jquery ajax with @UrlAction or string url and then parsing result value into target div.

```
$('#searchbutton').on('click', function() {
    $("#target").load("/Employees/Search"); 
});
```

Second one is using jquery load function to get result  of your partial view with model data into target div.

```
// jquery
$('#searchbutton').on('click', function() {
    var $detailDiv = $('#searchpage');
    var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Employees")';

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $detailsDiv.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

// controller

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    var model = GetModel(); // your function to get your model   
    return PartialView( "Search", model );
}
```

// html

```
<div id="searchpage">
    <!-- ...content... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but now it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in chrome developer tools and it highlights the first line of html in the partial view.

Comment: I have updated my answer with '@Html.Raw(@Html.Action("Search", "Employees"))'

Comment: The error has now become "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" and it highlights the line var val = '

Comment: The error is now the first error again which was "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and it highlights the first line of html in the partial view"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146207/discussion-between-hasan-and-chris-gong).

Comment: I saw your updated answer, willing to talk about it in chat?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an Ajax call, and loading the response:

```
$("#searchbutton").click(function () {

    var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Employees")';

    $.get(url)
        .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){
            $("#searchpage").html(response);
        });
});
```

If you are loading a static form, load it into a template script and copy it as needed:

```
<script type="text/template" id="search-template">
    @Html.Action("Search", "Employees")
</script>
```

Somewhere in your scripts:

```
$("#searchbutton").click(function () {

    var template = $('#search-template').clone().html();

    $("#searchpage").html(template);
});
```

I'm assuming the error you're seeing is because your HTML is formatted, so the "string" you think you're building is actually invalid in the generated markup - it'll have newlines, which are a problem in JavaScript strings.

Comment: Hi @Tieson T. Thank you for the reply. The Ajax call does work to an extent, but when I press a submit button, the post action will take me to another page which is undesirable because I want a single page application. Hence why I like Html.action more than Url.action. The second solution works a lot better but I was hoping to use the solution for switching between different partial views. For ex, if one partial view had input forms with text in them, switching to another view and back doesn't clear the text. You've already answered my question but I was wondering if u had any more suggestions

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your first point - if the content you're loading contains a form, then simply add a submit handler to the form after you load it, or add a filtered event handler to the body (or whatever container is closest that does not get removed when updating your page content). For the second, I would assume you either need to add a cache-buster, or clear the form when you load it.

Comment: To clarify my first point, I have a main view that will hold a partial view. However, if I click the submit handler in the partial view when it's loaded via Url.Action, the post action will redirect the user to another page just containing the partial view, leaving the main view. But for Html.Action, the submit handler won't redirect the user to another page. Is there any way for the post action to stay on the main view?